# Groupby category and subcategory

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having difficulty to wrapping my head around this problem. I have a CSV file with three columns: `category`, `subcategory` and `name`. I want to loop through the dataframe and print out something like this (simplified):

```
cat A:
  sub 1:
    names:
      name1
      name2
  sub 2:
    names:
      ...
```

So far, I have managed to write:

```
df.groupby(['Category', 'Subcategory'])['Name'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

But I am not quite sure how to produce the desired output from this dictionary. I was also thinking of creating nested lists, but can't really tell what the easiest way is to handle this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a nested for loop and boolean indexing like this seems overcomplicated compared to your one-liner, but I think it would get the job done and give you control over formatting. I'm pretty sure you'd need to iterate over your dictionary anyway to get the exact format that you want.

```
for category in df.category.unique():
    print(category, ':')
    cat_subset = df.loc[df.category==category]

    for subcategory in cat_subset.subcategory.unique():
        print('   ', subcategory, ':')
        subcat_subset = df.loc[(df.category==category)
                               &(df.subcategory==subcategory)]

        for name in subcat_subset.name.unique():
            print('names:')
            print('    ', name)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, combines `Name` into list.

```py
s = df.groupby(['Category', 'Subcategory'])['Name'].apply(list)
```

Then use [pandas.DataFrame.xs()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) to get values on level 0 and convert them to dict.

```py
d = {l: s.xs(l).to_dict() for l in s.index.levels[0]}
```

```
# pprint(d)

{'c0': {'s23': [1]},
 'c1': {'s19': [5], 's2': [3], 's5': [2]},
 'c2': {'s22': [2], 's56': [1]},
 'c3': {'s14': [5], 's2': [4]},
 'c4': {'s59': [1]},
 'c5': {'s1': [2], 's44': [1], 's87': [3]}}
```